# Looping through multiple subjects/sessions

Tags: matlab, for-loop, cell

Hi everyone I wrote a for loop which I want to use on multiple sessions of a subject. I have a datapath: C:\Users\Rouve\Documents\Promotion\tDCS\DATA\VP01\ where three folders: Session1, Session2, Session3 are located. Each of these folders contains 15 textfiles (test1.txt, test2.txt ... test15.txt). My goal is to run the for loop, which loads the 15 files inside one session, puts them into a cell, extracts the max values of each dataset inside of that cell and then averages every three max values over all sessions and puts them into a final file, so I would get 5 values per session. 
When I run the loop for one session it works and looks like this:

```
Volume_name='C:\Users\Rouve\Documents\Promotion\tDCS\DATA\VP02\Session1';

files=dir(fullfile(Volume_name,'*.txt'));
files={files.name}';
files_sorted=natsortfiles(files);
fileName=ls('*txt');

data = cell(numel(files_sorted),1);                %# store file contents
for i=1:numel(files_sorted)
    fname = fullfile(Volume_name,files_sorted{i});     %# full path to file
    data{i} = dlmread(fname, '\t', 19, 1);        %# load file
end
for i=1:length(data) %# get Max values of each trial (15 per session in total)
        MaxValues(i)=max(data{i});
end
MaxValues=MaxValues';

Mean_values=mean(reshape(MaxValues,3,[]));
Mean_values=Mean_values';
```

I just cannot seem to figure out how to construct the for loop so it does this automatically for all three sessions and outputs three variables, containing the 5 values of session 01, session 02 and session 03. I really hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate strings using `[]` as if creating a regular array and then process each folder within a loop while storing the mean data in a common array,

```
subdir = {'Session1', 'Session2', 'Session3'};

Mean_values = zeros(3,5);
for nv = 1:3
    Volume_name=['C:\Users\Rouve\Documents\Promotion\tDCS\DATA\VP02\', char(subdir{nv})]

    files=dir(fullfile(Volume_name,'*.txt'));
    files={files.name}';
    files_sorted=natsortfiles(files);
    fileName=ls('*txt');

    data = cell(numel(files_sorted),1);                %# store file contents
    for i=1:numel(files_sorted)
        fname = fullfile(Volume_name,files_sorted{i});     %# full path to file
        data{i} = dlmread(fname, '\t', 19, 1);        %# load file
    end
    for i=1:length(data) %# get Max values of each trial (15 per session in total)
            MaxValues(i)=max(data{i});
    end
    MaxValues=MaxValues';

    Mean_values(nv, :)=mean(reshape(MaxValues,3,[]));

    % Reset the data and MaxValues cell
    data = {};
    MaxValues = [];
end

save('mean_out.txt', 'Mean_values', '-ascii')
```

I'm not sure if I understood correctly (please clarify if not) - but you want an output file with the 5 means from each folder. This is what this program does - for each folder it finds the 5 means and stores them in a row of a common array `Mean_values`. After processing all the directories it saves the common array into a file 'mean_out.txt' using matlab `save` command for ascii format.

Since your program is not readily reproducible, I did not check it - if you run into an error, let me know.

Also this is one possibility - there are others, like appending the data into the file after each outer loop (nv) iteration in which case one would not need the common array. The reseting of reused variables at the end of the loop is not necessary since your data is all the same length, but it is good to keep in mind as a necessity for bug prevention when your data is not the same length.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply @atru, I'm sorry to bother again, but could you specify how I would move the code inside...I've tried to do it but it either shoots me an error message or it merely returns one variable (so for one session) - again sorry for being unable :/

Comment: You're right, there needs to be some more work done here. Will update soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate the help =)

Comment: I tried it and I receive the error: Subscripted assignment dimension
mismatch. Also I want to try and clarify my problem a bit better: I want the loop to go into the three folders one after the other (session1, session2, session3) and execute the function to load the .txt files as described, list them by name, take the max out of each of the 15 .txt files and take the mean of the max values 1-3,4-6,7-9,10-12,13-15, so 5 mean values per session. I hope I could explain it a bit clearer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RouVen - my bad, there was a bug. I tested it now with a simple but hopefully similar enough test case so it all should work now.

Comment: Glad to help :)